# Loading lookup table accounts with rust RPC client

Tags: rust, transactions, rpc, solana-client

I'm struggling to understand how do I get all accounts (static + dynamic) from executed on chain transaction using rust RPC client (`get_transaction`).

I kinda figured out that I can just make another request to RPC and retrieve all pubkeys of the lookup table account, then manually extend transaction static accounts with those dynamic accounts. But is that the correct way to do so? Isn't there a better way?

Also I found that metadata has `loaded_accounts` field. Is it safe to extend static fields with these loaded accounts from metadata? But not sure about this one also. If the accounts already in transaction metadata why there's no built-in way to access all accounts at once?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `get_transaction` from the RPC client, it will give you all of the accounts that were part of the transaction, both static ones and address-lookup-table ones, so there's no other work to do!

The `loaded_addresses` field gives you all of the accounts that were loaded from address lookup tables, so you can see which of the account keys came from lookup tables.

You can find the documentation for `getTransaction` at https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettransaction and for the `Transaction` object at https://solana.com/docs/rpc/json-structures#transactions